# Localhost:3000 won't update after installing devise in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How are you everyone?

I am a ROR newbie, and came across a problem after installing devise in gemfile. Localhost:3000 won't update and heroku webserver also shows the default ruby on rails page.

This is my current github file.

https://github.com/optinovation/omrails.git

Your help will be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You try removing the index.html file in public directory in your app and then proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `public/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to rename or remove the public/ind